# Row not displying data/values in Kendo Pivot Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, pivot-table, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Pivot Grid that has only one row, one column and one measure. I have it set up to display the dates on the top of the grid, the time intervals down the left side (rows) and the "Value" column should be the grid cell values.  I am able to get the dates to display across the top and I am able to get the measure to display in the grid but I am not able to get the Time intervals to display down the left side as a row.  My model is set up exactly as the data is in SQL (ForecastDate - Date, Forecast Interval - TimeSpan, Value - Decimal).  As seen in the Pivot Grid Screen Shot I am getting [object Object] next to the Forecast Interval.  I need to get the interval values to display.  How can I do this?

[SQL Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSjKM.png)

[Pivot Grid Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgqER.png)

```
@(Html.Kendo().PivotGrid<BluePrint.Models.ForecastFactor_Select_Result>()
.Name("arpPivot")
.ColumnWidth(75)
.Height(300)
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax()
    .Transport(transport => transport.Read(r => r.Action("Interval_PivotGridRead", "ForecastFactorDataMaintenance").Data("pivotParameters")))
    .Schema(s => s
         //.Model(m => m.Field(f => f.ForecastDate))
        .Cube(c => c
               .Dimensions(d =>
                {
                    d.Add(m => m.ForecastDate).Caption("Forecast Date");
                    d.Add(m => m.ForecastInterval).Caption("Forecast Interval");
                })
                .Measures(m =>
                {
                    m.Add("Value").Field("Value").AggregateName("average");
                })
         )
    )
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Add("ForecastDate").Expand(true);
    })
    .Rows(r =>
    {
        r.Add("ForecastInterval").Expand(true);
    })
    .Measures(m =>
    {
        m.Values(v =>
        {
            v.Add().Name("Value").Type("Value");
        });
    })
    .Events(e => e.Error("onError"))
    )
.ColumnHeaderTemplate("#= columnHeaders(tuple, member) #")
//.RowHeaderTemplate("#= rowHeaders(tuple, member) #")
// .DataCellTemplate("<span style='float:right' class='#= getDataCellClass(columnTuple, rowTuple, dataItem, measure) #'>#= (dataItem.value!='') ? kendo.parseFloat(kendo.toString(dataItem.value,'n2')):'-' #</span>")
//.DataCellTemplate("<span style='float:right' class='#= getDataCellClass(columnTuple, rowTuple, dataItem, measure) #'>#= (dataItem.value!='') ? (showtotal(rowTuple,dataItem)? kendo.parseFloat(kendo.toString(dataItem.value,'n2')):'-'):'-' #</span>")
)
```